About data type of source in react-admin v4
I'm building a screen with React-admin and typescript.
In the following code, the save button is disabled when moving from this field to another input field.
Is it no longer allowed to use Dot as the data type for source since v4?
<SimpleForm>  <SelectInput   source="person.name"   choices={name}   optionText="name"   optionValue="id"   fullWidth /> </SimpleForm>


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Using a nested data source with a dot should still be supported, as stated in the documentation
